# parse string with escaped double quotes to JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json string of the form

```js
let inputStr  = '{ "name" : "some string \" with double quotes"}';
console.log(JSON.parse(inputStr));
```

I wish to create a JSON object , but it gives `Unexpected token w`

I tried replace `\"` with `\\"` but could not get that working.

How can I either

- replace `\"` with `\\"`  OR
- create an object with that string

---

Actual code

I am parsing a file which contains JSON objects, one per line. Trying to convert that to CSV .

This is my transform stream code

```
const myTransform = new Transform({
    transform(chunk, encoding, done) {
    const vals = chunk.toString().split("\n");
    done(
      null,
      vals
        .filter(val => val && val !== "")
        .map(val=>JSON.parse(val)
        .map(val=> [val.name,val.body].join(','))
```

File contents

```
{"body":"Davey Crockett playing his fiddle and harmonizing with the Mexican Army band playing \"deguello\" outside the Alamo. TheMexicans then hold off their daily bombardment of the Alamo out of respect for his courage. Almost certainly never happened in real life but it sure is a badass scene in my opinion. That whole movie was.", "name": "xyz"}
```

Few of them contain escaped double quotes as shown above

Comment: How are you creating this JSON?

Comment: Show your code. See [mcve].

Comment: Why not just do `JSON.stringify({ name: "Some string with \" escaped double quotes" });` and find out?

Comment: @Archer the OP has a string and wants to make an object out of it, not the other way around

Comment: I got the JSON string from internet , some 30GB file with list of JSON strings in each line. Trying to parse it.

Comment: @Luca - I'm aware of that - it's in the question.  My suggestion would show him the string that he needs to make the object, and that's what they're struggling with ;)

Comment: You don't have escaped double quotes in your sample code. `'\"'` is the same as `'"'` (because that's how single-quoted string literals work). Show your real code.

Comment: @Skeptor didn't downvote, and since you edited with the snippet I've retracted my close vote.

Comment: @melpomene OP (eventually) provided runnable code that shows the error and is asking for a solution. What more do you want?

Comment: @JaredSmith As I said, the sample code provided by OP doesn't match OP's question. I can edit the code to match the description in the question (but then the error would disappear), or I can edit the question to match the code (but then it becomes unsolvable because it's invalid JSON). I suspect this is an XY problem, and I want to see real code.

Comment: `val && val !== ""` looks redundant. `""` is false anyway.

Comment: @melpomene fair enough.

Comment: Just trying to be extra careful, thats just a prototype code . But thats not the actual pain point.

Comment: There is no such thing as a JSON object.  There are objects and there is JSON, which is a string representation of an object.  You need to explain exactly why this is an issue, because I suspect you are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can first escape the \ with \ and then give it to `JSON.parse()`

Eg:

```
JSON.parse('{"name":"some string with \\\" escaped double quotes"}')
```

Comment: Although this is correct, giving the code to actually do the replacement would make it a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've converted your example to the below code. For demonstration purposes I've put the JSON text into a DOM element, not an external file, but the principle behind the code is the same. It runs without errors. There is no issue with escaped double quotes.

```js
const val = document.getElementById('fake-external-file').value;

console.log(JSON.parse(val));
```

```html
<textarea id="fake-external-file" cols="80" rows="5">
{"body":"Davey Crockett playing his fiddle and harmonizing with the Mexican Army band playing \"deguello\" outside the Alamo. TheMexicans then hold off their daily bombardment of the Alamo out of respect for his courage. Almost certainly never happened in real life but it sure is a badass scene in my opinion. That whole movie was.", "name": "xyz"}
</textarea>
```

(Technically this is not a real answer, but I can't embed code snippets in comments.)